# Googlesheets script - add incrementing numbers that repeat

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am new here. I need support with my code that I use for Googlesheets.

Background:

I am looking to create 1 to 12 in column A and repeat over and over again; something like this: 1, 2, 3, [...], 12, 1, 2, [...], 12, and so on.

Code:

I have written this code, but I am not sure where I am going wrong. Also not sure how to make it repeat after 12 every time. Help would be appreciated.

```
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
var currentValue = sheet.getCell(i,1).getValue();
var withString = 0;
range.getCell(i,1).setValue(val + 1);
}
```

Comment: You can use the MOD function.  `MOD(val,12)` gives the remainder from `val / 12`.  This will be in the range of 0 to 11, so add 1 to it: `MOD(val, 12) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using modulo will help on getting the numbers from 1 to 12.

One change you could make to your code, based on [Google recomendations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), is to update the data on the spreadhseet on batch operations. 
So instead of changing every cell one by one you could change the values for the whole range.

Example:

```
function addValuesToRows() {   
   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
       .getRange(1, 1, 100);   
   var numRows = range.getNumRows();   
   var values = range.getValues();   
   for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      values[i][0] = (i % 12) + 1;  
   }   
   range.setValues(values); //Setting the value to the whole range
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [modulo functions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Modulo_operation).

Think of it like a clock, where the values increase until they reach the modulo, at which point they start "looping". You'll want to print the value of `i % 12`, but modified because it's not zero indexed, so more like `((i - 1) % 12) + 1`.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 36; i++) {
  console.log(i, ((i - 1) % 12) + 1);
}
```

Result:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 1
14 2
15 3
16 4
17 5
18 6
19 7
20 8
21 9
22 10
23 11
24 12
25 1
26 2
27 3
// etc etc
```